# Spotify API GET Request to JSON

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to make a GET request on Spotify to get a JSON as depth as possible, using Python and Spotipy. I know how to get the album of an artis with all the attributes, I know how how to get the songs from the album with all the attributes and I also know how to get the audio features of the tracks with all the attributes. And I want to know if there is any possibility, to make a request, which gives me the all the attributes about one album, with all of the attributes of the songs in this album, and all of the audio features about the songs.

Answer (score 0):

So Spotipy doesn't have a API endpoint that does all that, but since you know you can get the songs in an album, just loop through the songs to get their attributes.

The API endpoint would be `track(track_id, market=None)`. More info [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.track)
And https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/tree/master/examples has great examples.